# Loading a native library from memory in Android JNI

Tags: android, c++, linux

Hi I am doing some experiments loading a native library from memory in Android.
I have opened a memfd using `syscall(SYS_memfd_create, "lib", 0)`, and this returns a valid file descriptor, I have written the content of the elf to the descriptor using `write()` then I am using the path of the lib in `/proc/self/fd/%d` and `System.load()` passing that path. The problem is that the memfd seems to be closed before the load happens:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/proc/self/fd/76" not found
...
```

Code:

```cpp
    int mem_lib_fd = syscall(SYS_memfd_create, "lib", 0);
    DBG_LOG_VA("memfd_create(): %d", mem_lib_fd);
    if (mem_lib_fd < 0)
        return -1;
    sys_write(mem_lib_fd, elf_buf, elf.size);

    char load_path[0xff];
    sprintf(load_path, "/proc/self/fd/%d", mem_lib_fd);
    DBG_LOG_VA("lib path: %s", load_path);

    jclass jSystem = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");
    jmethodID jSystem_load = env->GetStaticMethodID(jSystem, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jSystem, jSystem_load, env->NewStringUTF(load_path));
```

`dlopen()` used on the same path returns NULL and `dlerror` is the same message returned from the UnsatisfiedLinkError.
What's the problem?

Comment: If dlopen gives the same error message this has nothing to do with JNI.

Comment: @Botje I have also found this article but it does the same thing I do https://x-c3ll.github.io/posts/fileless-memfd_create/

Comment: Android is a special flavor of Linux. You cannot expect everything to work as-is. I suggest you get a debug build of Android and debug the dlopen function.